# Slow Visual Studio 2008 performance from IDE when viewing all data sources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, datasource

We are using Visual Studio 2008 for our development of our core product. We have a C# solution with roughly 5 projects and 250 data sources.

It takes anywhere from 15-25 seconds any time I do either Data > Show Data Sources, or if I click a (DataBindings) control property drop-down to bind a value of a control to a Data Source.

Aside from reducing the number of datasources we use, is there any way to speed up viewing/selecting data sources, especially when I go through and bind controls to the Data Source? I know I can copy and paste the (DataBindings) settings, instead of clicking the drop-down, but it would be nice to use the drop-down instead for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

How about considering to use Entity Framework if your database supports it. I think it can boost up design time performance. Creating your datasets using database schema and all of the binding properties programatically can also be a sollution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's a good suggestion; we are looking to switch to Entity in the future. Our core program is fairly large now and we still have our clients on .NET Framework 2.0, and we're a little heavy on projects so it will have to wait a while.